# How to achieve a copy of an unknown Class which inherits a known class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I need an array of varying class instances (here: B) which all share the same base class (here: A). 
The instances shall be stored as pointers, because they are referenced elsewhere (not displayed here).
I tried it this way:

```
class A {
public:
  A() {}
};

class B : public A {
  int m_magicValue;
public:
  B() : A() , m_magicValue(4711){}
  int getMagicValue() { return m_magicValue; }
};

class Manager {
  std::vector<A*> m_array;
public:
  Manager() {}
  virtual ~Manager() {
      for( size_t i=0; i<m_array.size(); i++ )
          delete m_array[i];
      m_array.clear();

  }
  void addA( const A& a ) {
    // here A is copied - here the problem occurs
    m_array.push_back( new A(a) );
//    createSomeReferences( m_array.back() );
  }
  A& getA( size_t idx ) {
    return *m_array[idx];
  }
};

int main() {
  B b;
  Manager manager;
  manager.addA(b);
  B& copiedB = (B&) manager.getA(0);
  int magic = copiedB.getMagicValue(); // magic is some random stuff instead of 4711!
  return 0;   
}
```

The Manager doesn't know anything about class B, it knows only A. 
The interesting thing happens in addA(): here it is attempted to new copy B and to store a pointer in the array.
But as expected it doesn't work as expected ;-)
copiedB.getMagicValue(); returns a random value.

The reason is relatively clear: Instead of B's copy constructor A's copy constructor is used, so only the A parts are copied.

So now my question:
Is there a good way to achieve such a copy, which inherits the whole class hierarchy, even though only the base class is known?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a virtual "clone" function (sometimes colloquially called a "virtual copy constructor"):

```
struct A
{
    virtual ~A() { }
    virtual A * clone() const = 0;
};


struct B : A
{
    virtual A * clone() const
    {
        return new B(*this);
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
void addA(A const & a)
{
    insert(a.clone());
}
```

Using raw pointers is terribly silly, though, and it'd be better to make the clone function, as well as the container, typed on `std::unique_ptr<A>` (and the code is otherwise nearly identical).

(You are probably asking yourself now, "why isn't there a version of `unique_ptr` that already does a deep, virtual cloning, maybe called `value_ptr<A>`? That's a good question.)

Comment: Thank you for the incredibly quick answer :-) And thanks for the hint with the unique_ptr!

Comment: @user2328447 would be greater to heve one intermediate class `template<class T> A_clone_impl : A{virtual A * clone() const
   {
      return new T(*static_cast<const T*>(this));
   }
};}`